# Scaling new data LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm-stateful

I have a trained stateful LSTM model that with time series data for a set period, however new data might come in that falls outside of the `MinMaxScaler` I've used.

For example the minimum value I have in my training set is 0.8 and the maximum is 1.5. Now new data comes in with a value range outside of that, say `[0.7, 0.75, 0.7, 0.6]`. How do I handle that? I've tried to find an answer to this but I'm not sure when I'm doing a new prediction how the scaling works.

Do I need to use the `MinMaxScaler` on all the data that I have including the new set, or do I just keep using the scaled MinMax result from the training set?

If this is a silly question, I'm sorry but I either missed this or simply cannot find it, thanks!

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you so much it has been wracking my brain.